# Eclipse Won't Recognize BLU Dash 3.5 As An Active Android Device

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, smartphone

I got a new Gingerbread phone to try to develop on, but Eclipse won't recognize it.
I put it into debug mode already.

The Win7 Device Manager shows a problem with 4 Qualcomm HSUSB devices, this is certainly related to the phone.
Windows update is unable to find any updates for it.
I couldn't find any drivers support downloads from BLU either.

About the phone:

- Andriod version: 2.3.5
- Kernel version: 2.6.38.6-perf
- Hardware version: A5.V1.2
- Build number: BLU_D170_v03_GENERIC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make contact with BLU service, and they e-Mailed me a driver that only works on 32-bit Win7, not 64-bit :-(

I figured out that I can still test my apps on my DASH 3.5 by uploading the .apk file to a webserver & using the phone to browse to that link.  Android will recognize that .apk is an app file it can install.  So you could also distribute your own apps to anyone this way, without using any of the Android stores|markets at all.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try using the Google USB driver?

For me, in device manager, I had an unknown device listed as "Android device" with a yellow exclamation point over it. Right click it, then choose update driver software. Then choose browse my computer, then choose let me pick from a list of devices...

Then click the Have disk button, and point it to the google usb driver (this should be downloaded via the SDK manager). It will be in the folder where your SDK stuff gets downloaded in the /extras/google/usb_driver folder. When browsing, select the inf file in this folder.

You should get three options that pop up, choose Android ADB Interface. It will then install the generic usb driver so you can connect your phone to ADB.

Note: I have the BLU Dash 4.0, but the driver should work on just about any android device.

Comment: I find in Dev manager the phone shows up as "Other" "Qualcomm HSUSB Device".  When I try to update the driver by browsing to that folder, the system says it doesn't find drivers for my device, even though the google usb .inf is right there.

Comment: You made my day. I have months trying to root my BLU Touchbook Pro via ADB. And I though that I didn't have the right drivers. Read your answer and in fact the device with no driver associated. Followed your instructions then Root Genius and voila. Big thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all, are you able to transfer data to the phone normally? If you can, don't bother with the second part below.

If you can't transfer data, look at this second part. When you bought the phone, did it come with a driver disc? If it did, install the drivers from there. If it did not, try checking the official manufacturer site to see if there's a driver online.

Comment: No, it didn't come with a disc.    
As I said in the question, I have not found any drivers online.

Comment: Weird. Normally phones would either have driver downloads or a driver disk. You still haven't answered if you're able to transfer data.

Comment: No data transfer is possible.  It doesn't show up as a removeable disk in windows explorer, and Eclipse doesn't seem to find it either.

Comment: If it can't do data transfer, forget about Eclipse finding it.
Anyway, try turning off the debug mode first and see if the phone can be detected.