# Android ADB USB Interface Types

Tags: android, usb, adb, protocols, winusb

[A previous post mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18602304/eclipse-wont-recognize-blu-dash-3-5-as-an-active-android-device) when you install a USB driver on windows a pop-up shows three options of interface types. While looking into the inf file there are three interfaces:

```
SingleAdbInterface          = "Android ADB Interface"
CompositeAdbInterface       = "Android Composite ADB Interface"
SingleBootLoaderInterface   = "Android Bootloader Interface"
```

Are there any documents or descriptions of the protocols or features on these interface?

Comment: While I found a blog based on reverse engineering http://blogs.kgsoft.co.uk/2013_03_15_prg.htm. But any more official documents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows ADB uses the generic [WINUSB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/usbcon/automatic-installation-of-winusb) driver. The `adb` binary handles the protocol all by itself.

The official documentation can be found at:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/adb/+/master/OVERVIEW.TXT
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/adb/+/master/SERVICES.TXT
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/adb/+/master/protocol.txt

Comment: The links a (no longer public) available.